# how to add svg text tag a value that return from javascript function

Tags: javascript, text, svg

I try to add a value into the text tag of a svg file that is returned from a function in javascript, something like this:

```
<svg width="6cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 600 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[  
function ShowString(){
return "HelloWorld";
}
]]></script>

<text x="0" y="50" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="50px" fill="red" ><script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[ShowString();]]></script>
</text>
```

How can I return the text and see it when I open the svg file without d3.js.
I want to do it all in the same file svg I create...
thanks,
beni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="6cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 600 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text id="txt" x="0" y="50" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="50px" fill="red"></text>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
      function ShowString(){
        return "HelloWorld";
      }

      document.getElementById('txt').textContent=ShowString();
    //]]>
  </script>
</svg>
```

Your second script tag executes a function that returns a string. But the string isn’t assigned to anything, so effectively the second script does nothing.

Not even `document.write()` would work there, because SVG documents don’t have that.